# Vim regex: + has to be escaped, * does not. Why?

Tags: vim, regex

Suppose you want to select lines that are: optional whitespace, followed by a positive integer, followed by more optional whitespace.

Here's a regex that works for this:

```
:g/^\s*\d\+\s*/
```

The `*` operator is not escaped, while the `+` is.  Escaping `*` breaks the regex.  So does un-escaping `+`.

Is there a good explanation for this?  Ideally something to make the rule intuitive.  With vim I've always struggled to write regexes because of unusual escaping rules, so I'd love some insight that'll make everything click for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's for historical reasons, and it would break compatibility if it were changed. However, you can prefix your pattern with `\v` to turn on "very magic" so you don't have to do special escaping. See `:help /\v`.